# Como habilitar o right-click(com a opção nova guia) em um input ou button

Tags: html, css

Tenho um `input` que gostaria que ao clicar com botão direito aparecesse a opção `abrir link em uma nova guia`.

Como posso fazê-lo, é possível apenas com `css` e  `html`, levando em consideração que esse mesmo botão disparará um `submit` ?

Comment: Tipo algo assim: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egpMEP ?

Comment: eu pensei em abrir a janela nativa do SO mesmo, mas que no click para nova aba ele já abrisse a pagina resultado do submit... mas é tipo isso

Comment: Eu não sei manipular isso. Até mais, abraços.

Comment: Tmb naum heuheuhue

Comment: Eu acredito que não tem como. Nunca vi em toda minha vida. (25 anos, 8 de programador)

Answer (score 1):

Com javascript fiz um trocinho besta só de zoeira...

```html
<script>
    function detectLeftButton(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var button = evt.which || evt.button;
        if(button == 1) {
            // ação para o botão esquerdo
   
        } else if(button == 2) {
            // ação para a rodinha do mouse
        } else if(button == 3) {
            // ação para o botão direito
   
   document.getElementById("menu").style.display='block';
   
        }
    }

    window.onmousedown = detectLeftButton;
</script>

<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<div id="menu" style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:-2px; display:none">
 <form action="http://www.google.com" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Abrir em nova aba">
 </form>
</div>
```

Mas acho que este tooltip aqui com CSS puro seja perto do que vc quer:

[É possível fazer um tooltip com CSS puro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101968/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-fazer-um-tooltip-com-css-puro/101979#101979)

Com javascript, fizeram aqui um troço muito mais próximo do que o que vc precisa do que essa budega que eu fiz acima:

[Como criar um menu de contexto personalizado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112469/como-criar-um-menu-de-contexto-personalizado)

Mas ainda sim não controla o abrir de nova aba.

Comment: gostei desse action "http://www.google.com" , mas não é essa a intenção