# Desativar determinadas opções do context menu padrão

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso desabilitar as opções do menu de contexto da melhor forma possível, se tiver alguma forma nativa e que não seja difícil de desfazer, seria interessante.

Um exemplo para o resultado esperado é a tag de vídeo do site xvideos.com, eles também têm a opção "Salvar vídeo como ..." desabilitada, e o menu de contexto é o padrão, eu gostaria do mesmo resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit:

---

Não quero criar uma menu de contexto personalizado em javascript, apenas desativar opções do menu padrão, mesma que a forma seja javascript, mas não criar um novo.

Comment: No caso eu não quero criar uma menu de contexto personalizado, apenas desativar opções do menu padrão.

Comment: Então você ainda pode utilizar como base a [resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112472/3774) que esta na pergunta duplicada, basta você não usar o `menu`, veja o [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/L03ejcwq/).

Comment: Mas eu quero deixar o menu de contexto funcionando normal, apenas desativar opções dele, desativar ele totalmente poderia usar a resposta marcada como duplicada, mas não ao respeito do menu de contexto padrão.

Comment: Ok, entendi seu problema, não sei se isso é possível, vou indicar sua pegunta para ser reaberta, vale a pena você modificar esse trecho da sua pergunta `desabilitar as opções` para `desabilitar determinadas opções` ou algo parecido, também vale a pena você colocar que opções são essas que você quer desabilitar.  =D

Comment: Vou editar Icaro, vlw, e o exemplo que passei é de conteudo aberto, mas para quem se interessar na questão, vale a pena acessar qualquer video do xvideos, deletar uma div qe fica por cima dos videos e ver que na tag video, é o menu padrão mesmo.

Comment: Se você só quiser desabilitar o download da tag do html5 `<video>` talvez essa [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41136470/2456894) te ajude.

Comment: Pelo que dei uma olhada isso ai é aplicado no player da tag video, isso ja ta aplicado no meu projeto, ele tira o botão de download do player html5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A princípio não é possível habilitar ou desabilitar essas opções do context menu.

Como aparece no exemplo citado pode estar relacionado à forma como o conteúdo está sendo entregue ao browser e que ele não consegue fazer o download do conteúdo e não uma questão de html ou javascript.

Isso poderia ser pelo conteúdo ser do tipo stream e ou estar sendo entregue em chunks (apenas uma suposição).

O que você pode fazer é: Marcar na `controlsList` da sua `<video>` a propriedade `nodownload` e "desabilitar" o `contextmenu` do elemento em questão.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <video id="videoPlayer" width="400" controls 
                                      controlsList="nodownload"
                                      oncontextmenu="return false;">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pelo que vi realmente é em bloco, com ao decorrer do vídeo é baixado os blocos com o nome de hls-720p<n_bloco>.ts. e a requisição retorna tipo video/mp2t. Vou marcar sua resposta como solução, mas para aprendizado, você teria algum link ou orientação de como pesquisar para ter esse tipo de vídeo? pois pelo que vi o src do vídeo não muda, então é feito apenas uma requisição e acredito que o proprio navegador faça as restantes.. (Estou chutando..)

Comment: @HenriAzevedo Você deve pesquisar por smooth streaming ou adaptative bitrate.